# Check new email in gmail inbox using PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

So my current code is this in PHP:

```
$mailbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'example@gmail.com', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

This code allows PHP to see my email inbox using IMAP and it works fine.

Now my question is, how to make it so that It checks all the **new** emails in my inbox and outputs "`n` New Emails!" and marks each of them as seen automatically.

I would really appreciate It If someone were to shed some light on this as I am very new to IMAP and handling emails programmatically in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of `imap_search`[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) and `imap_setflag_full`[2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-setflag-full.php)

```
$mailbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'example@gmail.com', 'password');

// This gives an array of message IDs for all messages that are UNSEEN
$unseenMessages = imap_search($mailbox, 'UNSEEN');

// Keep in mind that imap_search returns false, if it doesn't find anything
$unseenCount = !$unseenMessages ? 0 : count($unseenMessages);
echo "$unseenCount New Emails!\n";

if ($unseenMessages) {
    // The second parameter of imap_setflag_full function is a comma separated string of message IDs
    // It can also be a range eg 1:5, which would be the same as 1,2,3,4,5
    imap_setflag_full($mailbox, implode(',', $unseenMessages), '\Seen');
}
```